# How get text content geckofx c#

Tags: c#, html, geckofx

i use geckofx c# to get the textcontext. why can't I get the textcontent result if the html element is like this

```
<div>
    <div class="text1">
        <div class="text2">Michael</div>
        <div class="text2">Andrey</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**output : null**

whereas if the html element like this

```
<div class="text">
    <div class="text1">
        <div class="text2">Michael</div>
        <div class="text2">Andrey</div>
    </div">
</div>
```

**output :
Michael, Andrey**

I use geckofx code like this

```
GeckoNodeCollection names = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByClassName("text1");
foreach (GeckoNode name in names)
{
    console.writeline(name.TextContent);
}
```

the difference that I see is in `<div>` and `<div class="text">`. I appreciate all the help you provide.

Comment: Hi - based on your sample, it *should* work in both cases. I suppose there is a problem somewhere else. I assume the code samples you provided are simplified a bit?